# How to display a table row once per page only?

Tags: css, paging, princexml

I am trying to display every odd instance of a table row, however there is another table intervening.

The (simplified) structure is:

```
<div class="question03">
    <table class="trendgraph">
        <thead>
            <tr class="q3_pageheader">....</tr>
            <tr>...</tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>...</tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="datatable">
        <thead>...</thead>
        <tbody>...</tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="trendgraph">...</table>
    <table class="datatable">...</table>
</div>
```

For this question, I am calling a 'table set' the set of one table.trendgraph table and one table.datatable:

```
<!-- this is a set -->
<table class="trendgraph">...</table>
<table class="datatable">...</table>
```

Two of these sets will fit on a single page. The entire section consists only of the enclosing <div> plus 1 to 6 sets.

The output is actually paged media: pdf via PrinceXML, thus, cross-browser compatibility isn't needed.

The challenge is: I want to show tr.q3_pageheader in the table.trendgraph table only once per page, the first time it appears. This row will occur twice per page.

My css first turns these rows off:

```
div.question03 > table.trendgraph > thead > tr.q3_pageheader {
    display: none;
}
```

Then I have been trying various things to turn the desired row back on:

```
div.question03 > table.trendgraph:nth-child(odd) > thead > tr.q3_pageheader {
    display: table-row;
}
```

I can get the first tr.q3_pageheader (only) to display by setting nth-child(1). Curiously, none of the tr.q3_pageheader rows display with nth-child(2) or nth-child(even). All of the tr.q3_pageheader rows display with nth-child(odd).

Note that when I remove table.datatable from the html, then all the nth-child settings work as expected.

I could obviously do work arounds here, such as setting a div around a 'page', or setting a class for the first instance of tr.q3_pageheader. This will be part of a system that will output various numbers of 'table sets'. If possible I would like to solve the issue in html or css only without requiring extra decision making in the backend.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question with this:

```
div.question03 tr.q3_pageheader {
    display: none;
}

div.question03 table:nth-child(4n+1) tr.q3_pageheader {
    display: table-row;
}
```

I've confirmed this works both in PrinceXML and webkit. Something similar would work in any case where you had a set number of tables per page.